# Ampersand in Querystring is breaking page render on Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, query-string

Strangely enough, anytime I have an `&` in an HREF to indicate querystring parameters I receive the following error on the Blackberry Curve:

```
Error encountered during XML parse: expecting ';'.
```

Is there any way to get it to accept & in querystrings?  Other mobile browsers don't like the `;` to separate querystring parameters.

NOTE: I am using ASP.NET 2.0 if that makes a difference.

Comment: http://www.somesite.com/Page.aspx?section=1&item=2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blackberry is (for once) correct. Your code is not valid XML (or HTML), as the [Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) will confirm.

> Is there any way to get it to accept & in querystrings?

Yes, the same way you get an ampersand into any attribute value or text content. HTML-encode it.

```
Fish &amp; Chips
<div title="Little &amp; Large">
<a href="/script.aspx?x=y&amp;a=b">
```

> Other mobile browsers don't like the ; to separate querystring parameters.

That's a server-side issue rather than a browser issue. Whilst the HTML4 spec [recommends](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#ampersands-in-uris) that servers accept `;` as an alternative separator character to `&`, precisely to avoid the annoyance of having to write `&amp;` so much, sadly not all servers actually allow this.

Comment: So when I want to break querystring paramters I will use &amp;?  Just using & to separate the parameters breaks it.

Comment: Use `&amp;` in an HTML attribute (`href`, `src` or anything else) to mean the `&` character which is used to separate parameters, yes.